# Is "leaking" context inside AsyncTaskLoader that bad?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, asynctaskloader

I have an AsyncTaskLoader that does some background task. While doing this task, it needs to access some views. (No I can't just get the values of the views beforehand - they are custom views, with some magic stuff attached to it - please just accept this)

However, this is causing a context leak because the AsyncTaskLoader is holding a reference to a Context object.

- Question 1) Are context leaks that bad? (my loader runs only for 100ms - 200ms)
- Question 2) Is there a way to hold a view without a context leak (I'm pretty sure not so this is just wishful thinking)

It's not that bad, right? Like the old views are garbage collected a fraction of a second later.- that's the only side effect, right?

For the record the view I need a reference to is `CropImageView` from https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper and the method I need to call from inside the Loader is `view.getCroppedImage(width, height, CropImageView.RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_INSIDE);`

(no I can't use the prepackaged async versions of getCroppedImage because of reasons)

Comment: Of course context leaks is bad, you need to avoid it. Use weakreference to hold your context/activity/view when access it from background thread. Check this link(it refer to AsyncTask only but can do the same with AsyncTaskLoader) maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809336/android-asyntask-use-weak-reference-for-context-to-avoid-device-rotate-screen

Comment: @TruongGiangDam I'm not really well versed in how the exact implementations of weak references work - but from what I can tell they are just normal references that don't prevent garbage collection. Problem is - I kinda need to use them in the AsyncTaskLoader - I don't want them to get garbage collected and transformed into null or anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, even minor leaks are dangerous because you'll never know how much memory it might leak. In your example, when any of the background tasks is holding the reference to `context`, it won't allow `context` to be garbage collected thereby leaving a wasted memory. This is fine for small objects but giant objects like `context, Bitmaps` holds tons lot of memory without letting it collected by GC.

Assume, you started a `Loader` from `Activity A`,

```
A -> x memory ( x ~ very large memory comparatively )
```

While still, the `loader`is in progress you changed the orientation of mobile, which creates a new instance of `Activity A` with the same amount of memory x. Ideally old instance of `Activity A` should be garbage collected but GC can't recollect old instance memory as it is Strongly referred to a background task.

Hence, you need to take care of leaks while performing background tasks, this can be done in two ways -

either cancel the `loader` on destroying the `activity` instance  (or)  pass `weak reference` of your `context` to a loader.

Answer (score 0):

Yes context leaks is bad,we have to avoid it manually.`AsyncWork` holds the reference to the `Context`, the `Context` cannot be GCed until the task is complete: the `Context` memory leaks. There are two solutions:

1.Use a `context` that is long-lived, anyway, the `Application` `context`.
2.Tie the life of the async task to the life of the `context` to which it hold a reference: cancel it in `onPause()`.